# unable to sort alphabatically when calling data from db

Tags: php

I am trying to sort alphabetically. I am calling data from database. In the table i am storing ID's of Make like Suzuki, Toyota. I have 1 table naming Make in which i am saving Makes like Toyota.
then i am adding into Models with respect to Make like Land Cruiser is a model and its Make is Toyota. i am inserting ID of the Make from Make's table. then on front end, i am converting the ID's back to Make's name. I want to show Makes name alphabetically.

Here what i do

```
<?php
$SelectMainCats = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM model");
$S_NO = 0;
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($SelectMainCats)){
$S_NO++;      
$getid          = $row['id'];
//converting ids to names                   
$main_make_query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM make WHERE id=".$row['make']);
$main_make       = mysqli_fetch_assoc($main_make_query);
?>
```

Front end calling

```
<td><?php echo $main_make['maker_name'];?></td>
```

Comment: _"I am trying to sort alphabetically."_ - you're not trying very hard. I'd expect to see an `ORDER BY` in your queries, or perhaps a `sort()` or `usort()` or related function in your PHP code.

Comment: Sorry, i used it already, but then my data stops displaying. I did this way 

$main_make_query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM make order by maker_name ASC WHERE id=".$row['make']);

Comment: @TeamThunder I suggest that you get your SQL query working correctly outside of PHP first.  As @Tangentially said, `ORDER BY` is the way to sort data.  If that does not work, then there might be something wrong with your data, such as blank column values.  I suggest that you find a query tool to inspect the table data, and to experiment with SQL queries.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running a query and looping through the result set to run more queries is almost always the wrong way to SELECT data. You should be using a JOIN to link the two tables, then one query will retrieve all the data, sorted in the order you want.

Based on this data:

**Makes**

```
id  makerName
1   Ford
2   Suzuki
3   Toyota
```

**Models**

```
id  makerId  modelName
1   1        Prefect
2   2        Swift
3   3        LandCruiser
4   3        Celica
5   1        Orion
6   2        Splash
7   1        Mondeo
```

This Query

```
SELECT b.makerName, a.modelName FROM models a join makes b on a.makerId = b.id order by makerName;
```

Gives this result

```
makerName  modelName
Ford       Prefect
Ford       Orion
Ford       Mondeo
Suzuki     Swift
Suzuki     Splash
Toyota     LandCruiser
Toyota     Celica
```