# nested while loop stops after first iteration PHP

Tags: php, mysql, loops, while-loop, nested

I'm fairly new to this so I am probably missing something very basic, but I am trying to write some PHP script. I want to normalize my main table of data, which is info on used cars, make, model, price, etc. So I have another table with all of the unique car manufacturers in, this stores the `makeName` with a unique id `makeId` In my script, I connect to the database, read in all of the data from the main table, run it as an SQL query, then store it as a variable. I do the same with the `make` table.

Then I try to run through a nested while loop to replace all of the strings in the main table in the `Manufacturer` column with the `makeId` from the `make` table so that I can link these two tables.  It works for one iteration then stops, I've tried adding `!==FALSE` after the `fetch_assoc` in either and both while loops, but that gives me infinite loops I think. Here is my code...

```php
<?php

include("conn.php");

$sqlAll= "SELECT * FROM carData";

$carDataResult = $conn->query($sqlAll);

if(!$carDataResult){
    echo $conn->error;
    die();
}

$sqlMake = "SELECT * FROM 000make";
$makeResult = $conn->query($sqlMake);  

if(!$makeResult){
    echo $conn->error;
    die();
}  

while ( $make =$makeResult-> fetch_assoc()){

    $makeID = $make['makeId'];
    $makeName = $make['makeName'];

    while ($row = $carDataResult->fetch_assoc()){
    
        $sqlUpdate="UPDATE carData SET Manufacturer = '$makeID'
           WHERE Manufacturer='$makeName' AND Manufacturer IS NOT NULL";
        
        $res = $conn->query($sqlUpdate);
 
        if(!$res){
            echo $conn->error;
            die();
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: It looks like `$carDataResult->fetch_assoc()` has only one row or the `die()` execute try to run `print_r($carDataResult->fetch_assoc())` and make sure you have more than 1 row, if there is only one row then the logic is correct.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/66324787/14853083

Comment: If you want to iterate through the same mysqli result set multiple times, you need to reset the internal pointer, using [mysql::data_seek()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.data-seek.php), before the next loop.

Answer (score 1):

About 10 mins after I posted the question, after staring at this all day, I realised that I didn't need a nested loop at all and wrote the code below, which is clunky but it solved the problem, but I like your solution better @TangentiallyPerpendicular...thanks for your help guys...

```
while ($make =$makeResult-> fetch_assoc()){

     $makeID = $make['makeId'];
     $makeName = $make['makeName'];

      $sqlUpdate="UPDATE carData SET Manufacturer = '$makeID'
      WHERE Manufacturer='$makeName' AND Manufacturer IS NOT NULL";
        
      $res = $conn->query($sqlUpdate);
 
      if(!$res){
          echo $conn->error;
          die();
      }
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

As a general rule, reading a result set and looping through it to run successive queries is the wrong way to deal with this sort of problem. You can do it all in a single query:

```
update carData set `Manufacturer` = (select `makeId` from `000make` where 000make.makeName=carData.Manufacturer)
```

Your entire program becomes:

```
<?php

include("conn.php");

$sqlAll= "update carData set `Manufacturer` = (select `makeId` from `000make` where 000make.makeName=models.Manufacturer) ";

$carDataResult = $conn->query($sqlAll);

if(!$carDataResult){
    echo $conn->error;
    die();
} else {
    echo "Update Successful"
}
```

As an aside, I'd create a new column (called, perhaps, `makeId`) in your `carData` table and insert the data there rather than overwriting the `Manufacturer` column. That way you retain the Manufacturer column if something goes wrong. You can drop that column later.

Comment: About 10 mins after I posted the question, after staring at this all day, I realised that I didn't need a nested loop at all and wrote this, which is clunky and solved the problem, but I like your solution better #TangentiallyPerpendicular...

Comment: For this to be valid , `select makeId from 000make where 000make.makeName=models.Manufacturer` would have to make sense. But plainly, it doesn't. Right idea though.

Comment: @strawberry Would you elaborate on "plainly, it doesn't". Whatever point you're making, it's not plain to me.

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular, this worked, I just had to change models.Manufacturer to carData.Manufacturer, as my main table is called carData, but other than that, it worked perfectly, thanks.

Comment: My bad - I transcribed the wrong table name ‍♂️. Hopefully you found it useful nevertheless.

Comment: I found it extremely useful, thank you so much